# In ECSlidingViewController, how to disable the top view from sliding off screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

So I'm trying to implement the ECSlidingViewController sample into my App.
[github source for this](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController)

The only thing I'd like to do to modify it, is prevent the TopView from completely sliding off-screen before it changes the contained view, and instead just keep the TopView in place but update it's contained view with it's new view controller that was selected from the menu. The Facebook app's take on this is exactly what I want, in case that sounded confusing.

After looking around for a while within the project, I've determined that it definitely (and obviously) has something to do with this line of code in the ECSlidingViewController.h:

```
- (void)anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:(ECSide)side animations:(void(^)())animations onComplete:(void(^)())complete;
```

I looked at where this gets called in the .m:

```
- (void)anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:(ECSide)side{
[self anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:side animations:nil onComplete:nil];
}

- (void)anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:(ECSide)side animations:(void(^)())animations onComplete:(void(^)())complete
{
CGFloat newCenter = self.topView.center.x;
if (side == ECLeft) {
 newCenter = -self.resettedCenter;
} else if (side == ECRight) {
 newCenter = self.screenWidth + self.resettedCenter;
}

[self topViewHorizontalCenterWillChange:newCenter];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^{
 if (animations) {
  animations();
}
[self updateTopViewHorizontalCenter:newCenter];
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
 if (complete) {
  complete();
 }
 _topViewIsOffScreen = YES;
 [self addTopViewSnapshot];
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   NSString *key = (side == ECLeft) ? ECSlidingViewTopDidAnchorLeft : ECSlidingViewTopDidAnchorRight;
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:key object:self userInfo:nil];
 });
}];
}
```

This is where I'm guessing the animation is being told how to animate, but I don't understand how any of this could be telling it to move off-screen. Am I overlooking something as simple as replacing something to `nil`? Perhaps there's another value somewhere that I haven't found? This is my first question on StackOverflow, and though I'm new to Obj-C in general, I have a pretty decent grasp on how it works. So I'm hoping to receive at least a tip in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Just use the following method

`- (void)anchorTopViewTo:(ECSide)side animations:(void (^)())animations onComplete:(void(^)())complete`

instead of

`- (void)anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:(ECSide)side animations:(void(^)())animations onComplete:(void(^)())complete`

Comment: Search & replace "self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:ECRight" to "self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewTo:ECRight" in the 'changeTopViewController' method in MenuViewController.m works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it's just the bouncing that you want to remove, then instead of calling:

```
[self anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:side animations:nil onComplete:nil];
```

call directly:

```
[self.slidingViewController resetTopView];
```